# Number of training samples vs. feature dimension in cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, feature-selection, discriminant-analysis

When training a multinomial classifier (7 different classes) with different feature sets, I am noticing that the learning curve error always peaks around the number of training samples that are equal to the number of features used in training. I am using k-fold cross validation with k=10 for generating the learning curve.

In the example below, I am using around 500 features for training. I am using a Gaussian Discriminant Analysis model for learning. If I change the number of features, the peak follows.

Is this expected? If so, what is the fundamental reason behind such a behavior?

[image]

Comment: What was the size of the test set? Did you vary that along with training data size?

Comment: The test set was set by the k-fold cross validation. In my case, since k=10 it would have been 10% of the full training set for each fold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably overfitting until the number of samples is significantly higher than the number of features. As the number of samples grow, so does the model precision. And the low measured error with number of samples << number of features is probably just the lack of precision in measuring it via cross-validation. Around n samples ~ n features these two effects balance each other out.

Comment: This sounds reasonable but why do the effects balance out precisely at the number of features used? What is special about that number?

Comment: Each additional sample starts to add to training instead of encouraging the overfitting.

Comment: Yes. However, it's not clear to me still why the balance between overfitting and and training happens at the exact number of features. Does it mean that the dimension of the data is in the entire feature set space? Or are you saying that the entire data set is overfit by the model? I'm not an expert at stats so this is not obvious to me. Any further clarification would be nice

Comment: Why do you use cross validation on the train test of you have plenty more test samples? I think that Deigo has a point. You use 10 fold cross validation on dataset smaller than 500, which means that you are verifying on few dozens. The idea behind cross validation is testing on samples from the same distribution that are new to the classifier. Since you have such samples, use them and check the results. Diego is also right regarding the overfitting.

Comment: @DanLevin Thanks for the additional insight. Let me see if I understand your comment correctly. For a low-count training set, say 100, each CV training fold set of 90 samples will be completely overfit by the 500 features. Then we test on the remaining 10 samples. Why is the test error low in this case? Wouldn't it be high due to extreme overfit?

Comment: There are two issues here. The first is the overfitting and the other is the error estimation. Using a training set of 100 you use for CV 10 samples in each round. this is a small number for estimation. Add to that noise that you probably have and you hurt your estimation reliability. I understand that you want to see how your classifier behave given the size of training dataset. If you have extra data, you can train your classifier on 100 sample and test it on other unseen 10,000 samples.

Comment: Regarding the overfitting note that a small number of sample might lead to other problems besides overfitting. In the other direction, classifier of low complexity (e.g., the majority rule) won't overfit even when the training set is small.

Comment: @DanLevin Understand and agree about handling low-count training sets. My question was more focused on why the error peaking when performing cross validation. In your previous comment you imply that the estimation error in small training sets would hurt the accuracy, but my experiment shows that the error is improved as the set gets smaller! Maybe this is what you mean by estimation reliability

Comment: Yes, I meant that when you measure the accuracy on a small set, the measure accuracy is less reliable.